# 16.04 LTS: Drives not recognised when moved from older MoBo/CPU

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, hard-drive, bios

After updating my old build, some drives are not recognised, not by bios, not by Ubuntu. If recognised by bios, a drive is also seen by Ubuntu. Drives are:
Sony multi BD/DVD/CD. Worked perfectly in my old build.
OCZ Agility 240 GB system drive. No earlier problems with this drive.
Seagate Barracuda 2Tb data drive, always working without errors.

Builds:
Old: Gigabyte MoBo, AMD Phenom II x 4 965, 2GB RAM, psu Corsair AX760
New: Asus MoBo, Intel i7 6700, 32 GB RAM, psu Corsair RM750x
Both Builds run on MoBo internal graphics, i.e. there is no graphics card involved in either case.

A similar OCZ drive is readily recognised and works fine, so this is now the system drive in my new build.I hope someone has encountered similar problems and found the solution. I have searched all over the web but can't find the way to fix it anywhere, neither on Askubuntu.

Thanks, 
Carsten

Comment: So you can't even install? Do I understand you correctly? Does BIOS use UEFI or legacy mode?